# Why does readHTMLTable cannot successfully read premier league tables for May month?

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping

The [official Premier league website](http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb.html) provides data with various statistics for league's teams over seasons ([e.g. this one](http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html?season=2013-2014&month=MAY&timelineView=date&toDate=715215600000&tableView=CURRENT_STANDINGS)). I used the function ***readHTMLTable*** from [XML R package](https://www.google.rs/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2ovPszs3MAhUGkiwKHUwlBOcQFggkMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FXML%2FXML.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGar_hTrONPwwnW_PX41JUF-jkimg&sig2=HGsfcdnzTdoLgQ3-nq-wBA) to retrieve those tables. However, I noticed that the function can not read tables for **May months** while for others it works well. Here is an example:

```
april2007.url <- "http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html?season=2006-2007&month=APRIL&timelineView=date&toDate=1177887600000&tableView=CURRENT_STANDINGS"
april.df <- readHTMLTable(april2007.url, which = 1)
april.df[complete.cases(april.df),] ## correct table


march2014.url <- "http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html?season=2013-2014&month=APRIL&timelineView=date&toDate=1398639600000&tableView=CURRENT_STANDINGS"
march.df <- readHTMLTable(march2014.url, which = 1)
march.df[complete.cases(march.df), ] ## correct table

may2007.url <- "http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html?season=2006-2007&month=MAY&timelineView=date&toDate=1179010800000&tableView=CURRENT_STANDINGS"
may.df1 <- readHTMLTable(may2007.url, which = 1)
may.df1 ## Just data for the first team

may2014.url <- "http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html?season=2013-2014&month=MAY&timelineView=date&toDate=1399762800000&tableView=CURRENT_STANDINGS"
may.df2 <- readHTMLTable(may2014.url, which =1)
may.df2 ## Just data for the first team
```

As you can see, the function can not retrieve data for May month.

Please, can someone explain why this happens and how it can be fixed?

**EDIT AFTER [@zyurnaidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309235/zyurnaidi) answer:**

Below is the code that can do the job without manual editing.

```
url <- "http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/league-table.html?season=2009-2010&month=MAY&timelineView=date&toDate=1273359600000&tableView=CURRENT_STANDINGS" ## data for the 09-05-2010.

con <- file (url)
raw <- readLines (con)
close (con)

pattern <- '<span class=" cupchampions-league= competitiontooltip= qualifiedforuefachampionsleague=' ## it seems that this part of the webpage source code mess the things up

raw <- gsub (pattern = pattern, replacement = '""', x = raw)

df <- readHTMLTable (doc = raw, which = 1)
df[complete.cases(df), ] ## correct table
```

Comment: I've tried and played with it for a bit, and it seems that the issue is in the html parsing process (readHTMLTable). Using other parsing methods in XML package produce the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK. There are few hints for me to find the problem here:
1. The issues happen consistently on May. This is the last month of each season. It means that there should be something unique in this particular case.
2. Direct parsing (htmlParse, from both link and downloaded file) produces a truncated file. The table and html file are just suddenly closed after the first team in the table is reported.

The parsed data always differs from the original right after this point:

```
<span class=" cupchampions-league=
```

After downloading and carefully checking the html file itself, I found that there are (uncoded?) character issues there. My guess, this is caused by the cute little trophy icons seen after the team names.

Anyway, to solve this issue, you need to take out these error characters. Instead of editing the downloaded html files, my suggestion is:
1. `View page source` the EPL url for May's league table
2. Copy all and paste to the text editor, save as an html file
3. You can now use either `htmlParse` or `readHTMLTable`

There might be better way to automate this, but hope it can help.

Comment: thank you for the solution. It works! However, I need to iterate url(s) calls and retrieve data frames many times, so I need a solution that can work without manual (by hand copy-paste-save) editing. saveHML function doesn't work...